# MySQL optimization question : Having 6 columns or having 15 columns

Tags: mysql, database-design, design-pattern

Was wondering,  is it better to split a table into three tables with approximately 6 columns each and using foreign keys, or using one table and have it have 15 columns ?

Most of the fields are varchars, with a few numbers here and there. 
Database is MySQL.

By better I'm mostly interested in insert and select speed.

*Just to clarify this is a one to one case for this particular table, data is mostly user data and attributes would be location age active gender etc. as pertaining to one user only.  And yes, I am trying to isolate hot columns from cold columns*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend vertical partitioning for three limited cases:

- A very hot column(s), such as "clicks" or "likes" or "views" which are being incremented so frequently that the updates are interfering with other operations.
- Some column(s) is quite big, yet not needed all the time, such as a the `TEXT` of some document or image (in a `BLOB`).  Even this is dubious, since InnoDB does something similar automatically.
- A set of columns are often missing from the main table, as in being optional.  Then, rather than making the set of columns `NULL` in the main table, use a `LEFT JOIN` to the secondary table and leave out the row when the data is missing.  It is dubious whether this helps more than it hurts.

An accidental way to get into having vertical partitioning is when you need to add some new columns for a table with lots of rows, but cannot afford the downtime to add the columns.  Instead, make a parallel table to hold the new columns.  Note, however, `ALTER TABLE .. ALGORITHM=IMPLACE` mostly eliminates the need for this technique.

40 columns is beginning to be too many; 400 is too many.  That is, 15 is not a problem *in itself*.

As for performance, yes, there will be some performance issues *in either direction*, as mentioned by other Answers.

If you are not talking about millions of rows, don't worry.

One of my Rules of Thumb:  If I can't expect a 10% improvement, spend my time looking elsewhere for optimizations.

Bottom Line:  Do what works best for *you*; worry about optimization *later*.

Answer (score 2):

If the tables have a one-to-one relationship (each row in Table 1 will tie to one row in Table 2, and one row in Table 3), Then both `INSERT` and `SELECT` statements will be likely to be slower (you have the same amount of data to insert, plus the foreign keys, and presumably additional indexes to update when inserting; when selecting, you've got the additional overhead of joining the tables together).

However, most of the time, when discussing this sort of thing, each row in Table2 and Table3 will tie to multiple rows in Table 1 (or, Table3 will tie to multiple rows in Table2 instead of Table 1). For example, if you have an `employee` table with fields `division`, `division_address`, `division_city`, `division_state`, and `division_zip`, you could move those to a `division` table; and, presumably each employee would tie back to one division, and each division could have many employees.

In this case, an `INSERT` may be faster (you may have differences in index structure, but in most cases you'll be inserting 6 columns in each row, not 15), and a `SELECT` may be slower (having to join the tables together to get all the data involves extra work; however, in some cases, queries might be faster, if the indexes on Table2 or Table3 provide faster ways to narrow down the total number of rows that need to be checked; even in the worst case, we should reduce the amount of data that has to be read in to process the query).

However, do not ignore the other benefits of normalization. By only entering in the `division` information (to use my example above) once, we avoid typos leading to each division having 7 different names in the employee table. We make updating the division name or address much simpler (and avoid locking up the employee table while this happens). And, we store (in most cases) quite a bit less redundant data in the database, giving us space savings as well.

However, the best answer to your question is probably going to be "try it and see". We don't know your data, or whether a difference of (say 2%) in query speed is critical in your environment.

In general, I would recommend starting with a more normalized database (again, in terms of my example, splitting `employee` and `division`), and only denormalizing (putting `division` back into `employee`) if performance is unacceptable, and testing shows that merging the two tables will bring performance back up to acceptable standards. That's because it's much harder to take the division data entered for each individual employee and accurately combine it into your actual division structure (due to those aforementioned typos and such), than it is to copy the normalized `division` data, and copy to each `employee` row tied to it.

Comment: Thanks RDFozz  I've edited my question, as you implied it is a one to one in my case.

Answer (score 2):

This is a common denormalising pattern called 'vertical partitioning'.

A scenario where this can be useful is when most of your queries only cover a small number of columns in the table. And if the less needed columns are large (blobs for example).

By 'folding away' the less used columns you can fit more rows per page. And more in the various caches.

Also, suppose the less used data would benefit from compression, but the hot data would not. Now you have put it in another table you can compress it without compromising the other.

The penalties for doing this is inserts and deletes will be slower due to having to make extra queries, referential integrity checks, obtaining extra locks, maintaining the redundant indexes for the foreign keys.

Updates on the key column will be more expensive as will have to cascade to the other rows and their indexes.

Reads spanning multiple tables will have to be joined so will take longer.

More disk space will be used as the key column will be stored and indexed for each table.

Database is now more complex and harder to maintain.

As with pretty much all optimisations, don't do it unless you need to.

Comment: Hi Tony, Yes I am trying to isolate hot columns from cold columns. It appears    that vertical partitioning might spell trouble...

Comment: @Marin it's all relative, if you are having performance problems then you have to do what it takes.